# How to remove phrases from massive excel sheet

Tags: html, css, excel, e-commerce

I am trying to remove specific HTML tags from product descriptions in a large excel file.

The file contains 499 rows averaging 3650 characters each. I am attempting to remove `<span>` and `<font>` tags from the descriptions so that the html for each product is cleaner, however I keep getting errors saying the formula is too long.

I already removed the `<font>` and `<span>` tags from the product's titles by using Find & Replace to remove `<font*>` and `<span*>`.

Is there a better program or method to remove these tags from this huge list of descriptions?

Answer (score 0):

Using the Find & Replace feature is already a great way.  Just be sure to fill in each tag for the "Find what" section and blank for the "Replace with" section.  After that, hit Replace All and they should all be removed.

[image]